# when using yahoo maps the "X" (close button) in the smart window is showing up on the upper left

Tags: window, location, yahoo-maps

i am using code right out of the examples in yahoo maps api, but when i click on a smart window i get the close button (x) in the upper left.  the only thing i am changing is the html in the smart window but i dont understand why that would affect the location of the close button.   also, i dont see any documentation on how to change this on the yahoo maps api web site.

Comment: mind to add some links to the examples and your changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look in your page CSS for anything that floats `img` tags left or positions them absolutely (think along those lines).

One debugging method would be to temporarily turn off your page's CSS to see the result.